# Export table into excel Angular 5

Tags: excel, angular, export

I am trying to export my table into excel sheet here I am generating my html table using json data dynamically.

I am using this code to generate my table in angular:

```
   var table = document.createElement("TABLE")  as HTMLTableElement;    
  var row,header,cell1, cell2;
  var data = chart.options.data;
  // table.style.border = "1px solid #000"; 
  header = table.createTHead();
  row = header.insertRow(0);
  table.setAttribute("id", "myId");    
  cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  // cell1.style.border = "1px solid #000"; 
  // cell2.style.border = "1px solid #000"; 
  cell1.innerHTML = "<strong>Districts</strong>"; 
  cell2.innerHTML = "<b>"+rain_fall_type+"_Value</b>"; 
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j< data[i].dataPoints.length; j++){
      // console.log(data[i].dataPoints[j]);
      // console.log(data[i].dataPoints[j].label);


      row = table.insertRow(1);
      cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      // cell1.style.border = "1px solid #000"; 
      // cell2.style.border = "1px solid #000"; 
      cell1.innerHTML = "<strong>"+data[i].dataPoints[j].label+"</strong>";
      cell2.innerHTML = data[i].dataPoints[j].y; 
    }
  }    
  // document.getElementById("chartContainer").innerHTML = "<h1>"+rain_fall_type+" "+year+"</h2>";
  document.getElementById("chartContainer").appendChild(table);
```

This is generating a table and a values I am trying to use : https://www.npmjs.com/package/tableexport this library to export my table. When I am adding html table and run this code:

```
  var n =  new TableExport(document.getElementsByTagName("table"));
```

inside ngoninit I can see three buttons and all of them work fine but. When I am generating a dynamic table using above code I don't see any button to export.

I have added a button and on that click I am using this:

```
  myEvent(event) {
   var n =  new TableExport(document.getElementsByTagName("table"));
  }
```

When I click on this button I can see all three buttons to export but none of them is clickable. Is there any way I can make it work with dynamic html table.

Comment: have you used https://github.com/luwojtaszek/ngx-excel-export ?

Comment: I don't see any example to export table

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the (click)="myEvent()" in your buttons, for example

```
<button (click)="myEvent($event)" type="button" tableexport-id="5bf287e5-xlsx" class="button-default xlsx">Export to xlsx</button>
```

But also, in myEvent you define

```
 var table = new TableExport(document.getElementsByTagName("table"));
```

Shouldn't it be, just to be sure you grab the correct table

```
 var table = new TableExport(document.getElementById("myId"));
```

In Angular you should be using Template reference variables ( #myTable ) and getting a reference to them in the controller with @ViewChild('myTable')

Comment: this button is default one  for table export I am using one more button to just initialise new tableexport.